# A Java framework for online desktop application

Tags: java, desktop-application

We have a working ordering system written completely in PHP using the [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework). The system was made as a web application to be used easily across different machines over the web.

We have decided to change the system so that the client side will be a Java desktop application which will communicate with PHP web services on a server.

We are not building a [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) application, it's entirely a desktop application that's going to use sockets to talk to the server.

I need the framework to work in a manner similar to the MVC pattern where (for example) there is a class holding the events for the frame and another class holding the auto generated codes for the controls (something like the code behind in C#).

The framework should be easy to extend and to modify any part of it for complete control over the application.

I know there is many posts asking about the best Java framework, but I'm looking for something that will do most of its operations online.

I'm a PHP developer, and I have very little experience in Java so please bear that in mind when recommending a solution.

Comment: @Sudantha: yes I check it and as I said before we are building a desktop application purely in JAVA. We don't need to convert anything to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main open source frameworks that I know of that are available for Java are [Eclipse RCP](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php), [NetBeans RCP](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/), and [Spring RCP](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html). In all cases, RCP means Rich Client Platform. Eclipse's uses SWT as the underlying windowing tookit, the other two use Swing.

I'm much more familiar with Eclipse RCP than the other two, and I find consider it a mixed bag. As a framework I think it is nice in that it provides good methods for setting up most of the things a typical application requires and separates concerns nicely while still allowing for good reuse. I find SWT to be an uglier API than Swing in general though, but not really a deal breaker. It will also require you to become familiar with OSGi as it is built on top of it. It sounds to me like it would be worth your time to check it out.

Comment: What can you say about Spring RCP? It it a mature project?

Comment: I looked at it around 5 years ago and it looked very promising at the time, but not far along enough for my needs. I haven't followed the development since then so I'm not sure how it has progressed I'm sorry to say. I mostly included it here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build a Java desktop application, I would recommend [Java Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). It's the default Java GUI Framework.

If you want to do operations online, you can use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and the HTTPS protocol. This is the same HttpClient that is used in Android applications.